# skip double quotes when reading csv file using apache commons csv

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

```
Reader in = new FileReader(dataFile);
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreEmptyLines(true).withTrim().parse(in);

        // Reads the data in csv file until last row is encountered
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {

            String column1= record.get("column1");
```

Here the column1 value in csv file is something like "1234557. So whe I read the column it is fetched with the quotes at the start. Is there any way in Apache commons csv to skip those.

Sample data from csv file:"""0996108562","""204979956"

Comment: That screen dump is meaningless. Looks like a snapshot of Excel. Your code is not reading that, so how about you show us the actual content of the file referenced by `dataFile`? Paste into question as text, don't insert images. But, likely it will contain something like `"""0996108562","""204979956"`, which are two CSV quoted values, where the first character of a value is a quote. The CSV parser will **not** remove those, and it definitely shouldn't. That is an Excel quirk for entering numeric data as text, and has nothing to do with CSV. *Remove them yourself, or don't add them in Excel.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to reproduce using `commons-csv-1.4.jar` with this MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
String input = "column1,column2\r\n" +
               "1,Foo\r\n" +
               "\"2\",\"Bar\"\r\n";
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                                       .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                                       .withTrim();
try (CSVParser records = csvFormat.parse(new StringReader(input))) {
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        String column1 = record.get("column1");
        String column2 = record.get("column2");
        System.out.println(column1 + ": "+ column2);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
1: Foo
2: Bar
```

The quotes around `"2"` and `"Bar"` have been removed.

Comment: thanks for your help. But i have tried the code and it doesnt work. I have updated the question and uploaded an sample image of how the csv looks.

Comment: While reading i dont want the extra quotes which is there at the beginning.  With my existing code it reads the value with that quote.

Comment: Because the value *has* a quote, explicitly. The CSV parser is preserving the quote, *as it should*, because that leading quote has nothing to do with CSV. The CSV parser would be faulty if it removed the quote.

Comment: I can remove the quotes by writing code. I just wanted to know is there any built in method in commons csv to do that. like escape.

Comment: Well then, the answer is no, because they were not added by CSV, and CSV preserved them, as it is designed to do, and commons-csv is implementing the CSV parsing correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for clarification. I have removed the quotes manually by using String.replace("\"", "");

Comment: Try changing your input to ` "\"2\",\"Bar\"\r\n"` (there is a whitespace before the double quote starts) and your code will fail.

Comment: @Kakaji What does that have to do with this question/answer? The CSV data in the question is valid, and the CSV in this answer is valid, but adding a space makes it invalid CSV, so failing is not unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your requirement, you need to use [unescapeCsv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeCsv(java.lang.String)) from Apache's StringEscapeUtils. As the doc says:

> If the value is enclosed in double quotes, and contains a comma, newline >>or double quote, then quotes are removed.
>
> Any double quote escaped characters (a pair of double quotes) are unescaped to just one double quote.
>
> If the value is not enclosed in double quotes, or is and does not contain a comma, newline or double quote, then the String value is returned unchanged.

Comment: can you please check edited question. Now you will be able to understand the requirement.