# how to handle comma and double quotes in a csv file

Tags: java, escaping

we have a CSV file, where we have the following content where comma is coming inbetween the column value. the text enclosure here is **""**

here we have 4 fields separated by comma.

2121,john,**"Request for: some: create, new account ""SomeUser "" (so123) on GAP and server"**,34343

Since our delimiter is comma, how do we handle this in Java?

Comment: @Compass: Basically i need to handle this using escape character and text enclosure.. since we are using it in a tool. what is the escape character and text enclosure will split the string properly?

Comment: Use Apache commons csv. Also see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803587/skip-double-quotes-when-reading-csv-file-using-apache-commons-csv

Comment: There is not really such thing as "a CSV file", because the format is *not* well defined. In particular, use of quotes.